# Docker.Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, docker

Пытаюсь запустить образ, в котором есть [glassfish](https://github.com/reap/docker-glassfish3). Контейнер запускается, я пытаюсь на сервере развернуть приложение (war file).

Далее я пытаюсь получить доступ к приложению `localhost:8181/myapplication`. Домен запустился, я попал на главную страницу приложения и тут домен сам по себе останавливается и при обновлении главной страницы приложения я теряю связь с сервером.

В чем может быть проблема? Как правильно выполнить команду deploy и назначить порты (возможно, я ошибку допустил, но могу сказать одно - приложение разворачивается на сервере и я получаю к нему доступ, то есть ошибка в данном фрагменте мало вероятна).

Comment: @ alexander barakin подскажите что именно исправить в данном вопросе?

Comment: @andrey_KU, он уже исправил

Comment: @andrey_KU, а что-то в логах GlassFish написано?

Comment: @ Sergey Rufanov лог скачал, получил примерно файлов 8.из них один отвечает за ошибки-он пуст.